# Перевести тему на другой язык

Tags: wordpress, cms, wordpress-плагины

Я установил платную тему и сейчас не могу перевести её на азербайджанский язык.
Я сделал всё что требовалась:

1. Загрузил и перевёл .pot файл с помощью Poedit
2. Загрузил .po и .mo файл обратно в папку languages
3. Добавил строку в wp-config.php: `define( 'WPLANG', 'az_AZ' );`

Но что-то идет не так. Сам плагин темы изменяется, но тема остается как есть.   У темы есть плагин который я тоже переводил и он работает. Я загрузил другие плагины для перевода, но они тоже не работают.

Answer (score 0):

1. .pot файл - это шаблон. Он не переводится. Да и вообще современным темам не требуется.
2. Лангпак (файлы mo и po) загрузить лучше в системную директорию - `wp-content/language/themes/`. С имении textdomain-az.mo(.po), где "textdomain" - текстовый домен темы (не путать с доменом сайта!), а "az" - идентификатор локализации (азербайджанский в данном случае). Если же загружать в директорию темы, то с именем, согласно правил темы.
3. В wp-config.php ничего добавлять не нужно. Нужно выбрать язык в настойках.
4. Для упрощения переводов лучше использовать [плагин Loco Translate](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loco-translate/). Он же поможет и узнать правильность наименования лангпаков. Т.е. можно плагином создать новые, а потом заменить своими, правильно их назвав.

См https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization

Comment: A как мне найти строки которых нет в .pot файле ? Например на footer есть слова "Features", но я не могу найти его на .pot файле.

Comment: Забудь про pot вообще! Он не играет никакой роли. Поставь указанный плагин. Если разработчик темы правильно подготовил строки к переводу - ты всё найдешь в плагие. Если не подготовил, тогда может быть всё плохо. Но некоторые фразы могут меняться и в админке  темы (если разраб это реализовал, разумеется).